# iOS - VLC Mobile API not working (some missing file in MediaLibraryKit)

Tags: iphone, ios, libvlc

I have downloaded the related libraries and source code from [VLC for iOS](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html). I compiled it but  its not working. It shows that some *.a file is missing in *MediaLibraryKit* . I think its reference was not properly given or might be file removed.
I removed "MediaLibraryKit", downloaded it from the above mentioned link. Added MediaLibraryKit-1.1.0 into my Project. 
I replaced following import statements;

```
#import <MediaLibraryKit/somefile>
to -> #import <MediaLibraryKit-1.1.0/somefile>
```

Now it is showing me lot of error

- MediaLibraryKit-1.1.0/Sources/NSXMLNode_Additions.m:12:17: Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSXMLNode'
- Implicit declaration of function 'MLLog' is invalid in C99
- MediaLibraryKit-1.1.0/Sources/NSXMLNode_Additions.m:24:22: Instance method '-nodesForXPath:error:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Anybody tell me what I have done wrong? or anybody who has successfully compiled it?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find anything useful at that time. Now I have no use of it. But I will appreciate if you know anything useful related to this problem. It might help other users.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.videolan.org/IOSCompile/ helped me. If you are looking the same, Please look into the link. :)